# I can read output data but not http header with using custom apache module

Tags: php, performance, apache, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I come here to ask because I can't find any clear documentation anywhere on how to write a module that can read HTTP headers (particularly the status code) passed on from any 3rd party script (such as a PHP script) executed from the apache. So far, I can use this code to pick up contents of the HTML output and make a note of it in the error_log:

```
static apr_status_t outfilter(ap_filter_t *f,apr_bucket_brigade *pbbIn){
    const char *data;
    apr_size_t len;
    apr_bucket *pbktIn=APR_BRIGADE_FIRST(pbbIn);
    apr_bucket_read(pbktIn,&data,&len,APR_BLOCK_READ);
    request_rec *r=f->r;server_rec *s=r->server;
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_CRIT, 0, s, "SAMPLE: DATA READ: %s",data);
    return ap_pass_brigade(f->next,pbbIn);
}

static int addfilt(request_rec *r){
ap_add_output_filter("block:filt",NULL,r,r->connection);
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool){
    ap_hook_insert_filter(addfilt,NULL,NULL,APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
    ap_register_output_filter("block:filt",outfilter,NULL,AP_FTYPE_RESOURCE);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA sample_module={
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    register_hooks
}
```

I want to read the status because I want to stop potential script-kiddies from flooding my log at times with 20+ requests a second that point to non-existant items on the server.

Any idea how I can read the status? Even reading the first 10 or 20 bytes of the entire http header would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The status code is in r->status, and response headers are in the table r->headers_out and r->err_headers_out. Here's a simple tip -- If CustomLog can log what you're interested in, just read mod_log_config.c for how it's accessed given a request_rec.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just discovered the answer from experimentation, I needed to change AP_FTYPE_RESOURCE as the last parameter of the register filter function to AP_FTYPE_CONNECTION.